# VSTS package feed not pulling packages from upstream source (nuget.org)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have setup a new team project on VSTS for our development team and am using the `Package-Management` extension for publishing our NuGet packages. 
I have also enabled the public `nuget.org` feed as an upstream source for our internal package feed.

As recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/nuget/consume) & [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/concepts/feeds/upstream-sources) I have unchecked nuget.org as a package source within Visual Studio.
Now I expect the search to find packages published to this feed first 
and if not then fetch it from the upstream.
But this is not the case and am unable to add packages from nuget.org 
unless I enable nuget.org as a package source from within Visual Studio.

Packages from nuget.org (that where added by enabling nuget.org) start appearing in my private feed once I publish packages to my feed.(even after I uncheck nuget.org source) 
But I can't consume new packages directly from the upstream without enabling nuget.org as a source.

Have I misunderstood this is this supposed to be a build machine configuration rather than a developer machine configuration?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I don't want nuget.org to spam our internal feed. But when I don't enable "Use packages from NuGet.org", obviously the builds fail.

Comment: haven't used recently, but guessing from your comment, the behaviour hasn't changed much

Comment: @Vignesh.N Did you find solution to this issue? I am having the exact same issue that you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You missed this section in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/nuget/consume):

> If you're using upstream sources, package-versions in the upstream
>   source that haven't yet been saved into your feed (by using them at
>   least once) won't appear in the NuGet Package Manager search. To
>   install these packages:
>
> 1. On the upstream source (e.g. nuget.org), copy the Install-Package
>      command.
> 2. In Visual Studio, open the Package Manager Console from Tools -> NuGet Package Manager.
> 3. Paste the Install-Package command into the Package Manager Console and run it.

Comment: @KelsoSharp You need to go to https://www.nuget.org, search the desired package (ex: Newtonsoft.Json) and then you will see 3 tabs to install it, the first one for Package Manager (ex: Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 11.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (I'm using VS 2019), updated versions of packages from upstream should appear in the dropdowns automatically, except in the following case:

If `PackageA` depends on `PacakageB`, but `PackageB` is not explicitly installed (i.e. you didn't add it explicitly in your project's `Manage NuGet Packages` page), then `PackageB` will be frozen at the last version that was implicitly installed.

Example:

1. On your `Manage NuGet Packages` page you install `System.Text.Json` version 5.0.0.  This causes your app to be implicitly dependent on `System.Text.Encodings.Web` 5.0.0.
2. Some time later, you upgrade `System.Text.Json` to version 5.0.1.  There is also a new version 5.0.1 of  `System.Text.Encodings.Web`, but since `System.Text.Json` 5.0.1 depends on `System.Text.Encodings.Web` >= 5.0.0, the version already in your feed satisfies the implicit dependency.  Your feed will keep version 5.0.0.
3. Sometime later you need to update to `System.Text.Encodings.Web` version 5.0.1.  You search for `System.Text.Encodings.Web` on the NuGet package page, but notice that version 5.0.0 is the only version available!
4. **Solution**

   4.1. Click *Install* on version 5.0.0.  This will make the package an explicit dependency.

   4.2. Now, on the updates tab, you will see 5.0.1 appear as an update option.

Answer (score -2):

As you found, you do should also select nuget.org package source (both select you VSTS feed and nuget.org as package sources).

[image]

If you un-select nuget.org package source in VS, that means packages from nuget.org won’t be available.

For the purpose to search a package from VSTS feed first, and then search in nuget.org, you can achieve it by filtering packages from different package sources:

- To search a package (such as NUnit package) from VSTS feed (the name is new for below example) first:

  Sepecifying Package source as new, if there shows the related package(s) in browse list, then you can use the package(s) from VSTS feed. If there has no packages list, that means VSTS feed does not have related packages, then you can serarch from nuget.org as below step.

  [image]
- To serach the package (NUnit) from nuget.org, you just need to change the package source as nuget.org, then VS will list related packages which store in https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.

  [image]

Comment: i got this but the link said "If you enabled the nuget.org upstream source, uncheck the nuget.org package source." that got me confused.

Comment: Can you add the screen shot you meet? And doses the url for you upstream and nuget.org are same?